# iOS- Cannot Run Test Plan on CI tool

Tags: ios, circleci, fastlane, xcode15, xctestplan

I am looking for help with using TestPlans in my ci tool. My workspace consists of my main project and 2 frameworks, that are linked to my main project. I am using fastlane to run my test lane associated with my main app's scheme, which has my main project's tests targets and my 2 frameworks' test targets. When using fastlane locally, it seems to build every test suite and run tests accordingly, but on my CI tool (I am using CircleCI), it just runs my main project's test suite.

Can I get some help on this? I have tried to add a failing test to my CI tool and the tests still pass. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my test lane:

```
default_platform :ios

platform :ios do
  before_all do
    setup_circle_ci
  end

  desc "Runs UnitTest testplan"
  lane :test do
    run_tests(
    workspace: "MYWORKSPACE.xcworkspace",
    scheme: "MYSCHEME",
    testplan: "UnitTests",
    clean: true
    )
  end
end
```

I tried to run `fastlane test` in my config.yml file. Running this on my local machine seems to work, yet when I try to run this on CircleCI, it just runs my main target's test suite.